# Как перебрать динамические элементы при помощи javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jinja2

При рендере страницы выводится разное количество динамически подгружаемых комментариев.
Если юзер в сессии и юзер является автором комментария, то отображается кнопка для редактирования комментария.

```
{% for u in user %}
    {% if u.id == comment.user_id and u.id == session['user_id'] %}
        <span role="button" class="change-button">Править</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Комментарий отображается в тэге - р.
Так же, если юзер в сессии и является автором комментария, подгружается скрытая форма с текстовым input, которая появляется при нажатии на кнопку "Править".

```
{% for comment in comments_list %}
    <p>{{ comment.text_comment }}</p>

    {% for u in user %}
        {% if u.id == comment.user_id and u.id == session['user_id'] %}

        <form action="/update/comment/{{ comment.id }}" method="post" class="hidden-form d-none">
            <input type="text" name="comment-change" value="{{ comment.text_comment }}">
            <button type="submit">Изменить</button>        
        </form>

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Форма скрыта в css:

```
.d-none {
    display: none;
}
```

Как при помощи javascript сделать так, что бы при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку "Править" отображалась соответствующая скрытая форма?

Я пытаюсь так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".change-button").on('click', function(e) {
        $(".hidden-form").toggleClass("d-none")
    })
})
```

В данном виде, если подгружается несколько комментариев автором которых является юзер, то при клике по любой кнопке "Править", отображаются сразу все скрытые формы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо ориентироваться на индекс:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  [...$('.change-button')].forEach((button, index) => {
    $(button).on('click', () => {
      $('.hidden-form').eq(index).toggleClass('d-none');
    })
  });
})
```

```css
.hidden-form {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.hidden-form.d-none {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span role="button" class="change-button">Править 1</span>
<span role="button" class="change-button">Править 2</span>
<span role="button" class="change-button">Править 3</span>
<span role="button" class="change-button">Править 4</span>


<div class="hidden-form">Измени меня 1</div>
<div class="hidden-form">Измени меня 2</div>
<div class="hidden-form">Измени меня 3</div>
<div class="hidden-form">Измени меня 4</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Работает отлично! Сначала не понял [...$] этот синтаксис. Без него не работает.

Comment: @GaloGramma Обращайтесь! Вообще - это синтаксис [деструктуризации](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment). Но тут - это тоже самое, что если бы я написал `Array.from($('.change-button'))` просто короче. Про разницу можете прочитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548213/array-from-vs-spread-syntax)